# How to force balancing columns with bibliography if \printbibliography in \AtEndDocument command

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, two-column

I encountered an issue with balancing the bibliography using the `flushend` package. When the `\printbibliography` command is located in the preamble (and in my case, the entire code is in the class file), `flushend` stops balancing the last column. If I still need to use `\printbibliography` as indicated, is there a way to work around this issue?

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = utf8

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibdata.bib}
@InProceedings{Cao,
author="Cao, Cheng
and Caverlee, James",
editor="Hanbury, Allan
and Kazai, Gabriella
and Rauber, Andreas
and Fuhr, Norbert",
title="Detecting Spam URLs in Social Media via Behavioral Analysis",
booktitle="Advances in Information Retrieval",
year="2015",
publisher="Springer International Publishing",
address="Cham",
pages="703--714",
}

@article{Ramesh,
title = {An efficacious method for detecting phishing webpages through target domain identification},
journal = {Decision Support Systems},
volume = {61},
pages = {12-22},
year = {2014},
issn = {0167-9236},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dss.2014.01.002},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167923614000037},
author = {Gowtham Ramesh and Ilango Krishnamurthi and K. Sampath Sree Kumar},
}

@misc{Xu,
      title={A Transformer-based Model to Detect Phishing URLs}, 
      author={Pingfan Xu},
      year={2021},
      eprint={2109.02138},
      archivePrefix={arXiv},
      primaryClass={cs.CR}
}

@misc{Le,
      title={URLNet: Learning a URL Representation with Deep Learning for Malicious URL Detection}, 
      author={Hung Le and Quang Pham and Doyen Sahoo and Steven C. H. Hoi},
      year={2018},
      eprint={1802.03162},
      archivePrefix={arXiv},
      primaryClass={cs.CR}
}

@article{Wolpert,
title = {Stacked generalization},
journal = {Neural Networks},
volume = {5},
number = {2},
pages = {241-259},
year = {1992},
issn = {0893-6080},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/S0893-6080(05)80023-1},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893608005800231},
author = {David H. Wolpert},

}

@inproceedings{Choi,
author = {Choi, Hyunsang and Zhu, Bin B. and Lee, Heejo},
title = {Detecting Malicious Web Links and Identifying Their Attack Types},
year = {2011},
publisher = {USENIX Association},
address = {USA},
pages = {11},
numpages = {1},
location = {Portland, OR},
series = {WebApps'11}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\RequirePackage[backend=biber, %
    bibstyle=gost-numeric,
    maxnames = 10,
    babel=other,
    isbn=true,
    url=true,
    doi=true,
%   defernumbers=true,
    sorting=none,
    backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibdata.bib}



\setlength\bibitemsep{0.5\itemsep}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{1ex}
\AtEndDocument{
    \printbibliography
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-6]
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the flushend package prepends code to `\enddocument` and that means that your code is too late. It would be better if flushend would use the hook too, then one could use a rule to get the right order:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibdata.bib}
@InProceedings{Cao,
author="Cao, Cheng
and Caverlee, James",
editor="Hanbury, Allan
and Kazai, Gabriella
and Rauber, Andreas
and Fuhr, Norbert",
title="Detecting Spam URLs in Social Media via Behavioral Analysis",
booktitle="Advances in Information Retrieval",
year="2015",
publisher="Springer International Publishing",
address="Cham",
pages="703--714",
}

@article{Ramesh,
title = {An efficacious method for detecting phishing webpages through target domain identification},
journal = {Decision Support Systems},
volume = {61},
pages = {12-22},
year = {2014},
issn = {0167-9236},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dss.2014.01.002},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167923614000037},
author = {Gowtham Ramesh and Ilango Krishnamurthi and K. Sampath Sree Kumar},
}

@misc{Xu,
      title={A Transformer-based Model to Detect Phishing URLs}, 
      author={Pingfan Xu},
      year={2021},
      eprint={2109.02138},
      archivePrefix={arXiv},
      primaryClass={cs.CR}
}

@misc{Le,
      title={URLNet: Learning a URL Representation with Deep Learning for Malicious URL Detection}, 
      author={Hung Le and Quang Pham and Doyen Sahoo and Steven C. H. Hoi},
      year={2018},
      eprint={1802.03162},
      archivePrefix={arXiv},
      primaryClass={cs.CR}
}

@article{Wolpert,
title = {Stacked generalization},
journal = {Neural Networks},
volume = {5},
number = {2},
pages = {241-259},
year = {1992},
issn = {0893-6080},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/S0893-6080(05)80023-1},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893608005800231},
author = {David H. Wolpert},

}

@inproceedings{Choi,
author = {Choi, Hyunsang and Zhu, Bin B. and Lee, Heejo},
title = {Detecting Malicious Web Links and Identifying Their Attack Types},
year = {2011},
publisher = {USENIX Association},
address = {USA},
pages = {11},
numpages = {1},
location = {Portland, OR},
series = {WebApps'11}
}
\end{filecontents*}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
%\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{flushend}

\makeatletter
\def\initialize@flushend{%
    %%
    %%  Activates flushend package functionality.
    %%
    \global\let\saved@orig@@outputdblcol\@outputdblcol
    \global\let\balanced@@outputdblcol\last@outputdblcol
    % use hook instead of patching:
    \AddToHook{enddocument}[flushend]{\let\@outputdblcol\balanced@@outputdblcol}%
    \g@addto@macro\footnoterule{\vskip\z@}%
    \savingvdiscards=\@ne
    }
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}

\RequirePackage[backend=biber, %
    bibstyle=gost-numeric,
    maxnames = 10,
    babel=other,
    isbn=true,
    url=true,
    doi=true,
%   defernumbers=true,
    sorting=none,
    backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibdata.bib}



\setlength\bibitemsep{0.5\itemsep}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{1ex}
\AddToHook{enddocument}[my]{\printbibliography}

\DeclareHookRule{enddocument}{my}{before}{flushend} %ensure that flushend is later
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-6] \nocite{*} 

\end{document}
```

[image]